# Query on date or does not exist?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Trying to figure out if I can make this query work using mongoose and nodejs.

```
   Product.find({
        price: { $gt: 2, $lt: 3},
        date: { $gt: new Date() || $exists: false}
    }). exec(callback);
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to check if a date does not exist send it back or if the date is greater than today?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/):

```
Product.find({
  "price": { "$gt": 2, "$lt": 3 },
  "$or": [
    { "date": { "$gt": new Date() } },
    { "date": { "$exists": false } }
  ]  
}). exec(callback);
```

All arguments are generally an implicit AND, so just like it is *"price greater than 2 AND less than 3"* you are saying in addition *"AND the date is greater than this date OR date does not exist"*.

Just to spell out the logic in phrase form

With "multiple fields like this, **THEN** you actually use an [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)

```
Product.find({
  "$and": [
    { "price": { "$gt": 2, "$lt": 3 } },
    { "$or": [
      { "date1": { "$gt": new Date() } },
      { "date1": { "$exists": false } }
    ]},
    { "$or": [
      { "date2": { "$gt": new Date() } },
      { "date2": { "$exists": false } }
    ]}
  ]
}). exec(callback);
```

Comment: Can I do multiple $ors if I have date1 and date2 and want to do the same check for both? "$or": [
    { "date": { "$gt": new Date() } },
    { "date": { "$exists": false } }
  ]  , "$or": [
    { "date2": { "$gt": new Date() } },
    { "date2": { "$exists": false } }
  ]

Comment: @Lion789 Yes. This is one of the cases where you actually would use and explicit `$and` operator. For the same basic reason as the `$or`, the arguments are within an array. Not like you are doing it, but like I am doing it. See the answer content.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering is this allowed as well, keep getting an error for it: { _id: { $nin: [userObj.ids] } .... the array is [] empty but it gives me a cast CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[]" at path "_id" for model "Product"

Comment: @Lion789 If you have another question then [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) so that there is a clear statement to follow. Also make sure to search for existing answers before you do.